# AI(artificial intelligence)

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Consider the following problem:

The start state in a state space is being marked with the ID=1. Each other state x, will have two successors that are marked with IDs: 2x+1 and 2x. Show the part of this state space for states 1-20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved with a C++ program which generates a graphviz script.

```
// g++ generator.cpp
// ./a.out
// dot -Tpng graph.dot > output.png
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{ 
  std::ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("graph.dot");
  myfile << "digraph statespace \{ \n";
  for (int i=1;i<10;i++) {
    myfile << "  "<< i << " -> " << i*2 << "\n";  
    myfile << "  "<< i << " -> " << i*2+1 << "\n";  
  }
  myfile << "} \n\n";
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

[image]